# c++ cuda: cudaMallocManaged access outside of constructor

Tags: c++, cuda

I have a c++ class that uses cudaMallocManaged like so:

```
MyMatrix::MyMatrix(int new_rows, int new_cols, int padrr, int padcc)
{
  rows = new_rows;
  cols = new_cols;
  padr = padrr;
  padc = padcc;

  cout << "allocating memory" << endl;
  float *data;
  cudaError_t cudaStatus = cudaMallocManaged(&data, new_rows*new_cols*sizeof(float));
  if (cudaStatus != cudaSuccess){
      cout << cudaStatus << endl << flush;
      exit(1);
  }
  cudaDeviceSynchronize();
  cout << "allocating memory successful:" << cudaStatus << endl;
  // I CAN ACCESS DATA HERE
  //data[15] = 5.5; //fine
}
MyMatrix::~MyMatrix(void)
{
 cudaFree(data); // delete the data array
}
```

I have a header `.h` file too:

```
class MyMatrix
{

  public:
      MyMatrix(int new_rows, int new_cols, int padr, int padt);
      ~MyMatrix(void);

      float *data;
      int padr;
      int padc;
      int rows;
      int cols;
}
```

I can access the data array fine *within* this constructor.

However, as soon as I try to access it (read or write) outside of it, I get `terminated by signal SIGSEGV (Address boundary error)`. E.g.,:

```
MyMatrix *newmat = new MyMatrix(totalr, totalc, padr, padc);
cout << (*newmat).data[0] << endl;
```

Or

```
MyMatrix newmat = new MyMatrix(totalr, totalc, padr, padc);
cout << newmat.data[0] << endl;
```

How can I "persist" this pointer?

Comment: Does your class have a member variable called `data` in it?

Comment: @NathanOliver sorry I've edited my question. I forgot to include the header file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your constructor you create a local variable called `data`:

```
float *data;
```

After allocating the cuda memory and assigning the value to the local variable `data`, the memory address does not seem to be stored anywhere permanently. So, your memory becomes unreachable.

You have this line `newmat.data`, but in the constructro you never assigned any value to a member `data`. You did use just the local variable with the same name.

Comment: Sorry I updated my question. I have a header file that I forgot to include here.

Comment: ok, this answer was correct, even though I did have my header! The re-definition of data was the problem. Thanks!

Comment: It is not a *redefinition*. You defined a different kind of thing (local variable vs field) under the same name.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that in

```
MyMatrix::MyMatrix(int new_rows, int new_cols, int padrr, int padcc)
{
  rows = new_rows;
  cols = new_cols;
  padr = padrr;
  padc = padcc;

  cout << "allocating memory" << endl;
  float *data;
  cudaError_t cudaStatus = cudaMallocManaged(&data, new_rows*new_cols*sizeof(float));
  if (cudaStatus != cudaSuccess){
      cout << cudaStatus << endl << flush;
      exit(1);
  }
  cudaDeviceSynchronize();
  cout << "allocating memory successful:" << cudaStatus << endl;
  // I CAN ACCESS DATA HERE
  //data[15] = 5.5; //fine
}
```

the `data` you use in `cudaMallocManaged(&data, new_rows*new_cols*sizeof(float))` is the `float *data;` you declared in the line above, not the `data` member of your class.  You just need to get rid of the local `float *data;` so you use the `data` class member like

```
MyMatrix::MyMatrix(int new_rows, int new_cols, int padrr, int padcc)
{
  rows = new_rows;
  cols = new_cols;
  padr = padrr;
  padc = padcc;

  cout << "allocating memory" << endl;

  cudaError_t cudaStatus = cudaMallocManaged(&data, new_rows*new_cols*sizeof(float));
  if (cudaStatus != cudaSuccess){
      cout << cudaStatus << endl << flush;
      exit(1);
  }
  cudaDeviceSynchronize();
  cout << "allocating memory successful:" << cudaStatus << endl;
  // I CAN ACCESS DATA HERE
  //data[15] = 5.5; //fine
}
```